# Does azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-certificates libray support Azure AD Workload Identity

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I work on a project written in Kotlin and Spring, executed on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) and I am using the library `com.azure.spring:azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-certificates:3.14.0` with the following code:
`KeyStore.getInstance("AzureKeyVault").load(KeyVaultLoadStoreParameter(keyVaultUri)`
to retrieve `java.security.KeyStore`.

Previously I was using [Azure AD Pod Identity](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity) and the code was working fine, but when I switched to [Azure AD Workload Identity](https://azure.github.io/azure-workload-identity/docs/) and I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.azure.security.keyvault.jca.implementation.model.AccessToken.getAccessToken()" because "this.accessToken" is null
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.jca.implementation.KeyVaultClient.getAccessToken(KeyVaultClient.java:195) ~[azure-security-keyvault-jca-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.jca.implementation.KeyVaultClient.getAliases(KeyVaultClient.java:233) ~[azure-security-keyvault-jca-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.jca.implementation.certificates.KeyVaultCertificates.refreshCertificates(KeyVaultCertificates.java:142) ~[azure-security-keyvault-jca-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.jca.implementation.certificates.KeyVaultCertificates.refreshCertificatesIfNeeded(KeyVaultCertificates.java:130) ~[azure-security-keyvault-jca-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.jca.implementation.certificates.KeyVaultCertificates.getCertificateKeys(KeyVaultCertificates.java:122) ~[azure-security-keyvault-jca-2.6.0.jar!/:2.6.0]
```

I am also using [Azure AD Workload Identity](https://azure.github.io/azure-workload-identity/docs/) to communicate with CosmosDB, ServiceBus by relying on `WorkloadIdentityCredentialBuilder().build()` and everything works.

I assume that `com.azure.spring:azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-certificates:3.14.0` fails because the process of obtaining a token with [Azure AD Workload Identity](https://azure.github.io/azure-workload-identity/docs/) is somewhat different, but I am not sure what exactly is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get a `java.security.KeyStore` for a certificate from Azure KeyVault I used in the end the following approach (by only relying on `com.azure:azure-security-keyvault-secrets:4.7.1`):

```
val secretClient = SecretClientBuilder()
                    .vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl)
                    .credential(DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                    .buildClient()

val certificateWithKey = secretClient.getSecret(certificateName, null).value

val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS")
keyStore.load(Base64.getDecoder().decode(certificateWithKey).inputStream(), "".toCharArray())
```